# How to ignore ssl certificate in codeception chrome headless browser?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, codeception

I added in acceptance.suite.yml

```
chromeOptions:
    args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu","--test-type","--ignore-certificate-errors"],
```

but no luck? what can i do now

description  edit:

When i start tests in headless mode they get stuck, in the _output file (fail.png) i get blank page. So i think that they get to "Insecure Connection" page and can't get through it, and my question is how to avoid that page

Comment: What do you want? What is the issue? What is the usecase you are trying to solve?

Comment: When i start tests in headless mode they get stuck,
in the _output file (fail.png) i get blank page. So i think that they get 
to "Insecure Connection" page and can't get through it, and my question
is how to avoid that page.

Comment: @JesseAdravel, could you add that comment to your question as part of the description of this problem? Some context for other users, I'm experiencing this issue too. The behavior is that headless chrome gets stuck on the ssl page during automated tests if the page has a self-signed cert. This does not happen in 'headed' or normal mode. I believe the OP (and myself) would like to figure out a way to turn off ssl checks to prevent this issue. Let me know if that's not quite right, OP.

Comment: @SethWhite just did it, yes we have the same issue. But my temporary solution is to run selenium over docker, i think that docker has configured selenium to avoid ssl checks.(I assume that you use selenium too).
`sudo docker run --net=host selenium/standalone-chrome`

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739 ?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this already answered but according to codeception documentation
https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver

```
modules:
   enabled:
      - WebDriver:
   config:
     url: 'http://localhost/'
     browser: chrome
     capabilities:
         acceptInsecureCerts: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the argument you want is `allow-insecure-localhost`. This line worked for me to configure my `acceptance.suite.yml` file in CodeCeption.

```
- WebDriver:
    url: xxx.com
    window_size: false # disabled in ChromeDriver
    port: 9515
    browser: chrome
    capabilities:
        goog:chromeOptions: 
            args: ["allow-insecure-localhost","headless","start-maximized"]
```

This page lists all the options that chrome supports https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-insecure-localhost. Google themselves link to that (3rd party) page from their own page describing ChromeDriver config https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

```
ChromeOptions options = (ChromeOptions) caps.getCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY);
options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1366,768", "--no-sandbox");  
caps.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code .

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--headless", "--window-size=1920,1200", "--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```